# WordPress Rest API only returns content when posttype has editor capability

Tags: custom-post-types, javascript, rest-api, block-editor, editor

I am trying to request my post via the WordPress V2 Rest API in the backend. For whatever reason the post content is only returned when my custom post type has the `editor` support enabled. Is there a way to get the post content in the same request without having to enable the Gutenberg Editor?

My fetch request:

```
    apiFetch({
        path: addQueryArgs('/wp/v2/my_custom_post_type/' + postId, {
            context: 'edit'
        })
    }).then((post) => {
        console.log(post);
    });
```

My post type:

```
        register_post_type('my_custom_post_type', [
            'labels' => [
                'name' => 'My Custom Post Types',
                'singular_name' => 'My Custom Post Type'
            ],
            'public' => false,
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'hierarchical'=> false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-grid-view',
            'supports' => [
                'revisions',

            ],
            'has_archive' => false
        ]);
```